# BotFramework is supported in .Netframework 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, .net-framework-version

Do BotFramework is supported for. Netframework 4.7.2. or is it only supported for .Net Core. ?

Comment: the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/#supportedframeworks-tab) lists net461 as lowest framework.

Comment: Hi @SAURABH MISHRA is there anything else that we can assist you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do BotFramework is supported for. Netframework 4.7.2. or is it only supported for .Net Core?

Since Visual Studio 2019 has been released by default it generates
the bot template for bot SDK V4 using [asp.net core 2.1 and 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-create-a-bot-project?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#prerequisites). But V3 on [.Net 4.6.1 or later will still be supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#net-framework). New features development will be continue on  SDK V4 [asp.net core 2.1 and 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-create-a-bot-project?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#prerequisites).

**Support and Deprecation Notice**

[image]

You could have a look here [for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-availability?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-framework-sdk-version-3-lifetime-support-and-deprecation-notice).

**What Microsoft Recommend**

**Note:** [Microsoft recommend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#net-core) migrating to .NET Core, since the performance is very much improved.

**What Bot Developer Should Consider**

As you know while you would develop bot application you might be needed to integrate other eco-system like [adaptive card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#send-an-adaptive-card), [hero card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#send-a-hero-card) and so on to make your bot conversation more interactive. So when you would be using older than asp.net core 2.1 and 3.1 you might need to struggle with them.

Moreover, most of the [recent release v4.14](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/releases?page=1) has been developed based on [asp.net core 2.1. and 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-create-a-bot-project?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#prerequisites). In addition bot samples for customer on [Microsoft Official GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore) are developed mostly on asp.net core 2.1 and 3.1. As you can have look on [official document](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/README.md).

Comment: Can we get the running code for bot framework 4.7.2 ???

Comment: As described before last realease on `dotnet` released on [`net461`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_webapi/13.core-bot/packages.config). You can get here. Currently no new feature developing on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it does support at least 4.6.1, looking at there example code at

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_webapi/13.core-bot

The project file (CoreBot.csproj) has the following

`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>`